# Android Toolbar Submenu add margin

Tags: android, margin, toolbar, submenu

I'm adding a menu with a submenu to my Toolbar. Problem is, the submenu is sticking to the right edge of the screen. 
Is there any way to add just a little right margin to the "dialog" where the submenu is displayed? I've tried searching but came up empty.

Here is my code, just a simple menu with a submenu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_pdf_filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="@string/filter"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_filter_serial"
            android:title="@string/filter_by_serial_number"
            android:orderInCategory="100"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_filter_filetype"
            android:title="@string/filter_by_file_type"
            android:orderInCategory="200"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

[image: The submenu is sticking to the right side of the screen because of size constraint]

Comment: nope its because of material design it will come as it is shown

Comment: which support library version you are using?

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar hello, I am using com.android.support:design:23.0.1 and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1

Comment: @mugiwara528: in which device you get this?

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar Kyocera Qua Tab 01.. seems like a device issue

Comment: Yes its device issue because i have same support library in one of my sample its working fine

Comment: have a similar issue. need to add some margin to the menuitems textview as its getting ellipsized / cut off. been trying to fix it all day.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Kyocera Qua Tab 01 - turns out this was a device issue. I needed it to work anyway, and I found out that if I set it as an overflow menu, the right margin would appear, and then I explicitly changed the icon of the overflow button.

XML:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter_serial"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter"
    android:title="@string/filter_by_serial_number"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter_filetype"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter"
    android:title="@string/filter_by_file_type"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Android:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    Drawable drawable =  ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_action_filter);
    if(drawable != null) {
        drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
    }
```

If you ever need to reset the icon to its default image, you can download the resource here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2778684

Save the images to your project, and change the icon using the code above again.